# How to get distance between parent div and img tag with a selected class?

Tags: jquery

I have a thumbnail gallery and I want to get the distance between selected img and parent div(small-images|left side). I tried offset/position but someshow doesn't work. Please give me a hint or something. Thanks!

```
$(function(){
var $big= $("#big-image img");
var $small = $('.small-images img');
$big.not(':first').hide();
$small.last().addClass('selected');

$small.click(function(e){
    $small.removeClass('selected');
    var i = $(this).addClass('selected').index();
    $big.hide().eq(i).show();
});

$('.next, .prev').click(function() {
    var m = $(this).hasClass('next') ? 'next' : 'prev';
    var $t = $small.filter('.selected')[m]();
    if ($t.length) {
        $small.eq($t.index()).click();
    }
});
```

});

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqqqbqaz/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I try again since I misunderstood the question first time around.

You need to use `offset.left`. You have to get parents offset and selected items offset and subtract the parents from the selected. That way you get the selected items relative offset (to the parent):

```
var parentOffsetLeft = $(".small-images").offset().left;
var imgOffsetLeft = $(".selected").offset().left;
var relativeOffsetLeft = imgOffsetLeft - parentOffsetLeft;
```

Heres a demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/theagitator/qqqqbqaz/9/

Comment: And if this not what you were looking for, please be more clear on what you mean by _get the distance between selected img and parent div(small-images|left side)_

Comment: no is not what I am looking for. I will try de explain better: I want the distance in pixels between img that has the selected class(red border)  and left side of small-images div(black border).